# WordPress not updating the js file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am changing a JavaScript file, but it is not showing up in the browser.
I cleared browser cache, I purged the cache through wp-admin, I removed the deflate code from .htaccess, but still it doesn't show up.

```
themes/soundwave/js/prettyPhoto.js?ver=4.2.3
```

when I add any other number in the ver for example, in the url if I type:

```
themes/soundwave/js/prettyPhoto.js?ver=4.2.3.1
```

the change is shown.

Comment: Goto your frontend and Press `Ctrl + U` and try to click on your js link to make sure it's not broken.

Comment: How have you added the .js file to your theme? Did you use `wp_enqueue_scripts()` function ?

Comment: I always have this problem, it is annoying, if I could choose I would stop using WP altogether because of this

Answer (score 11):

During development, you could avoid the hassle of clearing the browser cache by passing a dynamic variable as the file's version when you enqueue it. For instance, the current time.

`wp_enqueue_script( 'prettyPhoto', 'prettyPhoto.js', array(), date("h:i:s") );`

Comment: wp_register_script( 'prettyphoto', vc_asset_url( 'lib/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), WPB_VC_VERSION, true );

Comment: wp_register_script( 'prettyphoto', vc_asset_url( 'lib/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), date("h:i:s"), true );

Replace that with this line.

Comment: after purging all caches, even with a timestamp at the end of the path, still loading the same version. only workaround i have so far is renaming the file and readding.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem. So at front-end page press Ctrl+U look at the script. If didnt changed, go to functions.php and try to define correct version.(in this exapmle 2.0.0)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-global-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js.js?ver=2.0.0', array( 'jquery'), '2.0.0', true );}
```