# Debug wordpress theme without updating script and style versions in functions.php

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, debugging, cloudflare

I am working on existing Wordpress theme. Every time when I update code of any style or script I need to update file version in functions.php file. By doing this I am able to work with updated styles and scripts through Firefox developer tools.

Updating the versions every time is very annoying and time consuming. I googled and found bunch of plugins for debugging, but nothing seems to be working.

Note: I'm using CloudFlare and NGINX webserver.  Does that potentially contribute to this problem?

Comment: I have a theme folder. inside the folder i have  styles and script files. For example i change theme style in sublime text editor and save it. After that i have to change the style file version in functions.php so that i can see lates style in browser

Comment: Thank you. I have disabled caching in Firefox but it doesn't help. I am using cloudflare. May cloudflare cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CloudFlare, then their CDN is caching your assets, which is why you are only seeing the updates when you bump your css / js file version numbers.

For development, CloudFlare offers a slick tool to put their site in "Development Mode", so you can see your changes without bumping version numbers.

1. Log into your CloudFlare account.
2. Go to "Caching".
3. Look for the "Development Mode" section, slide the toggle to "On".
4. Note - this mode automatically turns off after 3 hours, so you don't have to remember to turn it off - **however**, if you're developing for longer than this, you'll have to turn it on again.

For more info, refer to [CloudFlare Development Mode](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168246-What-does-Cloudflare-Development-mode-mean-)

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Dynamically updating the file version during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833622/wordpress-not-updating-the-js-file/31834007#31834007)

During development, you could avoid the hassle of clearing the browser cache by passing a dynamic variable as the file's version when you enqueue it. For instance, the current time.

Find the code where the files are enqueued, and make the necessary change as follows:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', 'custom.js', array(), date("h:i:s") );`

The function `date("h:i:s")` outputs the current time and passing that as the version number will auto-refresh your cache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am updating a theme of a live website. Will this approach cause weird effects on clients browsers? I don't want to keep date("h:i:s") after finishing the theme update. I want to return to normal version format like '2.0' after finishing the development proccess. Will turning back to for example to '2.0' show old style on visitor browser?

Comment: Not at all. Using a static version, like say 2.0, will not break anything. But note that the browser and the CDN will start caching your files and you may not observe the changes immediately. You'll have to do a hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. All replies were helpful. I figured out that exactly in my case the problem was due to NGINX cahcing. I disabled NGINX cache and it worked as intended. Cloudflare caching was a problem too.