# How do I refresh js file in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to refresh some of my edited js code which I have edited to **contact-form-7/includes/js/script.js** file. But it seems Its not refreshing my new added code in the browser? I have many links but none of them seems to solve my problem.

http://wpengineer.com/2292/force-reload-of-scripts-and-stylesheets-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

http://sabrinazeidan.com/force-css-js-refresh-wordpress-development/

[WordPress not updating the js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833622/wordpress-not-updating-the-js-file)

I have also tried adding version after url but it doesn't show anything in the browser .

http://www.xxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?version=1234

Comment: are you using any cache plugin, or did you set any expiry for js cache in .htaccess?

Comment: Yes [w3-total-cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/), and there is no expiry date in .htaccess.

Comment: try deactivating the w3-total-cache

Comment: Yes I have also tried that but it shows the same result in other browser.